# How should i file scss folders properly?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am working with one project and trying to make it responsive.My question is when I put components inside of App.js if there is a class with same name they override each other like that

```
--ExampleComponent1.js
--ExampleComponent1.scss

.custom-container {
  width: 50%
}

--ExampleComponent2.js
--ExampleComponent2.scss

.custom-container {
  width: 70%
}

const App = () => {
return(
<ExampleComponent1 />
<ExampleComponent2 />
)
}
```

It causes custom-container class overrided by examplecomponent2 cuz they both have same class name.
So my question is that i know i can use scss.module but should i use media queries in every seperated scss folder like that ? Is it good to use ? Because i am writing in every scss folder media queries 3 times ( for mobile - for tablet - for desktop ) . It seemed wrong to me. What should i do ? Hope i am clear enough.

```
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1279px) {
   .custom-container {
    width: 70%;
  }

  @media (max-width: 767px) {
     .custom-container {
      width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use BEM (block__element—modifier, e.g. login__form—select) naming conventions or moduled CSS.

Comment: hmmm so with that I can use all my quries in App.scss right? But sometimes i give css to p tag or h1 tag it causes all my p s  ( I mean in all page) change color or font size.
If i use module css i think i need to give my media queries in local scss because there is no chance to change their css on App.scss by reaching its name.

Comment: With .scss its easy to keep it scope. Just nest rules
  .login{
     p{
       color: whatever;
    }
  }